# using for loop to "read_pickle" and "to_pickle" a lot of data files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Linux and Ipython Notebook. I have a directory of pickled data files ('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills') containing date, bill_id, and sponsor_id (more than one bill per sponsor); I have a pickled data file (located in: '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/sbcommittee_id_pdf') with a column of all sponsor ids sbsponsor_id_pdf. I need to go into the directory '/home/.../senate_bills', open each pickled file, make a separate file that collects all of the bill_ids for each sponsor_id in sbsponsor_id_pdf file and then pickle the file, giving it a name according to the sponsor_id and a two digit number.

The code that I have so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import os.path
path = '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills'
path1 = '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf'
dirs = os.listdir(path)
for dir in dirs:
with open(path + "/" + dir) as f:

    df = pd.read_pickle(f)
    with open(path + "/" + "/sbcommittee_id_pdf", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        for sponsor in data['sponsor_id']:

            pdf = df[df['sponsor_id'] == sponsor]

            pdf.to_pickle('sponsor' + '_08bills.pdf')

            print (pdf)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError   Traceback (most recent call     last)
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas /io/pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
 44         try:
---> 45             with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
 46                 return pkl.load(fh)

TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/jayaramdas    /anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas  /io/pickle.py     in try_read(path, encoding)
 50             try:
---> 51                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
 52                     return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=False)

TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in read_pickle(path)
 59     try:
---> 60         return try_read(path)
 61     except:

/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
 55             except:
---> 56                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
 57        return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=True)

TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
 44         try:
---> 45             with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
 46                 return pkl.load(fh)

TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
 50             try:
---> 51                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
 52                     return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=False)

TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-40e7738e1c05> in <module>()
  8     with open(path + "/" + dir) as f:
  9 
---> 10         df = pd.read_pickle(f)
 11         with open(path + "/" + "/sbcommittee_id_pdf", "r") as f:
 12             data = json.load(f)

/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in read_pickle(path)
 61     except:
 62         if PY3:
---> 63             return try_read(path, encoding='latin1')
 64         raise

/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in try_read(path, encoding)
 54             # compat pickle
 55             except:
---> 56                 with open(path, 'rb') as fh:
 57                     return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=True)
 58 

TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: `with (path + "/" + dir) as f` makes no sense. Did you forget `open()`?

Comment: oops; yes I did. sorry! I'll correct and update!

Comment: `os.listdir` gives you both directories and files.  It is difficult to see how your directory structure is organized and where the files are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help.  I wasn't clear about the file location of the JSON file and how it relates to the path.

In general, you want to use `os.path.join(a, b)` so that your code works across multiple platforms (e.g. Mac and PC).

Note that you are missing a layer of indentation in your sample code just after `for dir in dirs:` (dir is a reserved word anyway and shouldn't be used).

You are also using your `f` variable twice. Try `f1` and `f2` or something more descriptive.

```
path = '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf'
senate_bill_dir = os.path.join(path, 'senate_bills')

data = pd.read_pickle(os.path.join(path, 'sbcommittee_id_pdf.p'))
data.columns = ['sponsor_id']
for my_file in os.listdir(senate_bill_dir):  
    df = pd.read_pickle(os.path.join(senate_bill_dir, my_file))
    for sponsor in data['sponsor_id'].unique():
        pdf = df[df['sponsor_id'] == sponsor]
        if len(pdf):  # Only save if there are records.
            pdf.to_pickle(str(sponsor) + '_08bills.p')
```

Comment: Alexander, i applied your code. I think you should be able to view it here: http://localhost:8888/notebooks/sorting%20raw%20data.ipynb#                  There was a small error:  File "<ipython-input-62-2837f473ef8f>", line 8
    with open(os.path.join(path, my_dir, sbcommittee_id_pdf) as f:
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

I'm working on it, but if you have any ideas please let me know!

Comment: Thank you for your help with this!
'['s113_sb_pdf', 's112_sb_pdf', 's110_sb_pdf', 's111_sb_pdf']'

these are the files that I need to collect the bill data from for each unique sponsor_id

Comment: s113_sb_pdf is the name of one of the files that I need to open and collect bill data from.

An error:
NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-91d46e76669a> in <module>()
      4 
      5 
----> 6 print(os.listdir('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf'))

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf'

Comment: Yes, 'df = pd.read_pickle('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/senate_bills/s113_sb_pdf')'
Works.

Comment: THree columns headers ( + index). date, bill_id, sponsor_id. Followed by the corresponding data

Comment: THe other file has one row for each sponsor_id. It is located at <df = pd.read_pickle('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/pdf/sbcommittee_id_pdf')>

Comment: This is a file. There is only one such file. It is composed of an index column and a column of sponsor ids. Neither of the columns have a header. I am trying to use the df.columns method to add a column header to the sponsor ids column.

Comment: I just applied the edited code. A small error: File "<ipython-input-105-4cdc08cd7f1a>", line 7
    with open(os.path.join(path, 'sbcommittee_id_pdf.p') as f_sub:
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax